# Ether.li transfer problem despite correct password

Tags: javascript, bug, ether.li

AFter entering correct passwort when trying to transfer ETH on ether.li (via browser), I always get an error message "Type error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'"...

Does anyone know what to do? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think this is a javascript error massage. Did you try to use a different browser? Do you have some browser plug-ins interfering with the pages code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fabian! Now I'm at least one step further.. But I now I have the next problem: My OTP password is not accepted although definitely correct.. I'm using Google Authenticator as selected during the sign-up process for ether.li. Is there some way to switch to authentication via SMS maybe?! Or do you know of any other solution?

Comment: Sry,  I can't help with that